# USB Audio Interface with DSP

Tags: audio, embedded, usb-device, dsp, development

I am looking to build an audio interface that can also use real-time DSP to process audio coming from (most important) and going into the host.

After some research, I have been zeroing in on the xCORE-200 Multichannel Audio Dev Kit but want to make sure it is the right kit for my intended purpose.

here is a link to a commercial product that is in line with what I'm thinking of doing: https://www.uaudio.com/audio-interfaces/arrow.html

The main important thing about this device from Universal Audio is that it allows the user to use real-time effects on the audio coming from the host, thus saving the host from having to do all the work which is ultimately what I would like to do with my own C/python based effects that I've been writing.

Comment: just a thought:  i wonder if a  GPU in a video card could be used to process audio data

Comment: @jsotola A GPU is great for parallel things, audio is very serial. I think just using a thread on the CPU would be simpler. GPU would make sense if he'd use some FFT techniques, something like [overlay-save method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overlap%E2%80%93save_method). Oh well, I guess it depends on how/what OP actually wants to do with his audio.

Comment: @jsotola exactly what Harry said. Also, unless you're processing hundreds of channels: for most things you'd want to do to real-time audio, your CPU is not going to even remotely have to break a sweat. It'd be really no use at all to use a GPU for that kind of workload.

Comment: Hi Steve! I think the project is very interesting, even without a purpose, but what exactly is the reason you want to safe your host computer from having to do the audio processing? As someone who's usually involved in real-time processing of signals on PC-type hardware, I can assure you that audio rates are really pretty benign and the kind of specialized processing hardware that can solve a problem that a PC couldn't would be pretty large indeed.

Comment: The xCORE things are still pretty cool, simply because they can do things like building beamforming microphone arrays that look like normal microphones to a PC, so that you don't need special software on the PC – that's *convenient* from a user's perspective, not technically sensible.

Comment: @jsotola  [I looked at how much load audio signal generation is and whether it pays to do it on a GPU](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32916536/is-there-a-constant-time-algorithm-for-generating-a-bandlimited-sawtooth/32931019#32931019) before.